# Hashmap keys will not work

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap which certain keys like "crash" and "crashes" which return the same response. I want to create a new HashMap that maps synonyms to a unique key in the responseMap (for example, map "crash", "crashes" and "crashed" to "crash" in the synonymMap).

```
 private void fillSynonymMap()
  {
    synonymMap.put("crash", "crash");
    synonymMap.put("crashes", "crash");
    synonymMap.put("crashed", "crash");
  }
```

What I am stuck on is how to input these keys so that I can simplify the code below.

```
 private void fillResponseMap()
{
    responseMap.put("crash", 
                    "Well, it never crashes on our system. It must have something\n" +
                    "to do with your system. Tell me more about your configuration.");
    responseMap.put("crashes", 
                    "Well, it never crashes on our system. It must have something\n" +
                    "to do with your system. Tell me more about your configuration.");\
   responseMap.put("crashed", 
                    "Well, it never crashes on our system. It must have something\n" +
                    "to do with your system. Tell me more about your configuration.");
}



public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> words)
{
    for (String word : words) {
        String response = responseMap.get(word);
        if(response != null) {
            return response;
        }
    }

    // If we get here, none of the words from the input line was recognized.
    // In this case we pick one of our default responses (what we say when
    // we cannot think of anything else to say...)
    return pickDefaultResponse();
}
```

Comment: Tell me more about your configuration.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain it a little more clearly. May be with some sample input and output. And those two maps should contain, and from where are they populated?

Comment: Please elaborate on your desired input and output. There is no context here.

Comment: I think I still don't get your question. What is that you would like to simplify?

Comment: but of course it wont get there, use if(response.equals(null) == false) return response;   nothing is null in java, you check here the reference, you will see you always return.

Comment: I have a HashMap which certain keys like "crash" and "crashes" which return the same response. I want to create a new HashMap that maps synonyms to a unique key in the responseMap (for example, map "crash", "crashes" and "crashed" to "crash" in the synonymMap).

Comment: so do you want in the new hashmap, if i go for key "crashed", "crashes","crash" itll all give me the same? that is: assume you have a map as follow: <i,j> ,<k,j>, <m,j> all give you j so you want in the second map to be simply <n,j> and if i search for the key k it will still give me the right one, or now do i have to give it the n key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little messing about I wrote a function that will look for a synonym, before returning  a default message.

```
public String getResponse()
{
    HashMap<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    responseMap.put("crash", "Hello there");
    // Load the response value.
    synonymMap.put("crash", "crash");
    synonymMap.put("crashed", "crash");
    synonymMap.put("crashes", "crash");
    // Load the synonyms.

    String input = "crashed";
    // Select input value.

        if(responseMap.containsKey(input))
        {
            // Response is already mapped to the word.
            return responseMap.get(input);
        }
        else
        {
            // Look for a synonym of the word. 
            String synonym = synonymMap.get(input);
            if(!synonym.equals(input) && responseMap.containsKey(synonym))
            {
                // If a new value has been found that is a key..
                return responseMap.get(synonym);
            }
        }
        // If no response, set default response.
    input = "This is a default response";
    return input;
}
```

As you can see the function first checks if the key exists. If it doesn't, it attempts a synonym. If that synonym doesn't pass the test, it will move to the default code at the bottom, which will set input to some default value and return that instead :)

Comment: I can see what you did her but both crash and crashed are keys in the responseMap which return a response. I have a HashMap which certain keys like "crash" and "crashes" which return the same response. I want to create a new HashMap that maps synonyms to a unique key in the responseMap (for example, map "crash", "crashes" and "crashed" to "crash" in the synonymMap).

Comment: Well in terms of memory, your responses look like they're quite long. Why consistently store the same response several times when you can use the above method, and the only repetition is in the synonym map? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second map.

The first map translates the synonyms to the basic key, which in turn can be used for the second map with the answers.

This also allows flexible extension of synonyms without enlarging the actual response map.

Besides, in this case you can actually use another type as key for the answser map. It just has to be same as the value type of synonyms maps.

That way, you could also use

```
Map<String, YourEnum> and Map<YourEnum, String>
```

with EnumMap as implementation of the Map interface.

Comment: Will the actual response map be enlarged? He's adding the same string constant 3 times, as far as I can see.

Comment: Not for the actual response. However, you would get two additional keys in the keySet of the map.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do but I don't know how. I have a HashMap which certain keys like "crash" and "crashes" which return the same response. I want to create a new HashMap that maps synonyms to a unique key in the responseMap (for example, map "crash", "crashes" and "crashed" to "crash" in the synonymMap).